# angular-universal | firebase-admin | code: 'app/invalid-credential' |socket hang up on

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-universal, firebase-admin

```
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
var serviceAccount = require('./keys/keyfile.json');
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "https://test.firebaseio.com"
});

var registrationToken = "--some-key--";

var payload = {
  notification: {
    title: "$GOOG up 1.43% on the day",
    body: "$GOOG gained 11.80 points to close at 835.67, up 1.43% on the day."
  },
  data: {
    stock: "GOOG",
    open: "829.62",
    close: "635.67"
  }
};


function panelMessage(){
admin.messaging().sendToDevice(registrationToken, payload)
  .then(function(response) {
    // See the MessagingDevicesResponse reference documentation for
    // the contents of response.
    console.log("Successfully sent message:", response);
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    // console.log(serviceAccount);
    var date = new Date();
    console.log(date.toString());
    console.log("Error sending message:", error);
  });
}
```

I run this code through node and it work but when i add it in angular-universal

> server.ts

file.. it give the following error..

> Error sending message: { Error: Credential implementation provided to
>   initializeApp() via the "credential" property failed to fetch a valid
>   Google OAuth2 access token with the following error: "socket hang up".
>       at FirebaseAppError.Error (native)
>       at FirebaseAppError.FirebaseError [as constructor] (D:\angular2MH\firebase -
>   panel\panel\node_modules\firebase-admin\lib\utils\error.js:39:28)
>       at new FirebaseAppError (D:\angular2MH\firebase - panel\panel\node_modules\firebase-admin\lib\utils\error.js:84:23)
>       at D:\angular2MH\firebase - panel\panel\node_modules\firebase-admin\lib\firebase-app.js:119:23
>       at ZoneDelegate.invoke (D:\angular2MH\firebase - panel\panel\node_modules\zone.js\dist\zone-node.js:232:26)
>       at Zone.run (D:\angular2MH\firebase - panel\panel\node_modules\zone.js\dist\zone-node.js:114:43)
>       at D:\angular2MH\firebase - panel\panel\node_modules\zone.js\dist\zone-node.js:502:57
>       at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (D:\angular2MH\firebase - panel\panel\node_modules\zone.js\dist\zone-node.js:265:35)
>       at Zone.runTask (D:\angular2MH\firebase - panel\panel\node_modules\zone.js\dist\zone-node.js:154:47)
>       at drainMicroTaskQueue (D:\angular2MH\firebase - panel\panel\node_modules\zone.js\dist\zone-node.js:401:35)
>   errorInfo:    { code: 'app/invalid-credential',
>        message: 'Credential implementation provided to initializeApp() via the "credential" property failed to fetch a valid Google OAuth2
>   access token with the following error: "socket hang up".' } }

I checked the time (read at many place that could be the issue) and they are all synced.. 
Can anyone help me out with the issue? I'm using this repository [repository](https://github.com/angular/universal-starter)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From Firebase-Support,
Angular-Universal is not a library that we officially support. so no OAuth can be provided.

To deal with the issue, I made another server for firebase and made api calls from universal server. Its working fine now.